# How can I build a ladder that runs on rails?

Tags: ladder

I have a kitchen with a high ceiling and want to install an extra level of shelves to make use of the space. To reach the top shelves, a ladder is required. Ideally, it would be attached to a rail and be removable.

[image: ladder on rails]

My question is: How can I build this type of thing? What parts do I need to make the rail and ladder myself?

Comment: Can we can clarify terms to help the OP? Those are often called "library ladders" in english. That term gets you close enough in google to shop yourself.

Comment: Are you looking to save time or money? If so, you'd probably be better off buying the proper ladder hardware in the first place.

Comment: try here: http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=32228&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&utm_content=pla&utm_campaign=PLA&gclid=CLb9x6-Y0LcCFSJqMgod-msABw